# Show Δ in the header of a jqgrid table

Tags: html, jqgrid

I have a table and i would like to have Δ symbol in one of my header.

```
$('#id').jqGrid ({
colNames : [
        'sl.no',..., 'Δ'
    ]
})
```

But rendering i am getting **Î”** in html.

Please suggest a way to print Δ symbol.

Comment: Check out your File-Encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HTML special character instead.

`&Delta;`

```
$('#id').jqGrid ({
colNames : [
        'sl.no',..., '&Delta;'
    ]
})
```